# UTC Offset in Seconds to Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, utc

i've been working with an api that returns the time in an UTC offset like '7000' in seconds, im trying to pass to a date like  '2020-01-01T01:56:40.000Z' or time like '1:12:03 PM'

i have tried this but returns a wrong date, as if i was giving it a value in ms

```
var utcSeconds = 7000;
var d = new Date(7000); 

console.log(d);  // 1970-01-01T00:00:07.000Z
```

All i've been able see online is the oposite proccedure or  different procedure,
hope you can help me, Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to achieve. What does "returns the time in an UTC offset in seconds" mean? What is your expected output? What should `yourfn('2020-01-01T01:56:40.000Z')` or `yourfn('1:12:03 PM')` return?

Comment: The Api is returning '32400' as timezone for Tokyo,Japan right now, im trying to convert that preferably to  a format time like '1:12:03 PM'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to find a canonical IANA timezone that matches the UTC offset you get from the API. These look like 'Etc/GMT-9' and have a fixed UTC offset. (See [`List of tz database timezones`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones))

Once we have this timezone we can use [`Date.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) to format the local time.

We can wrap all this up in a function `formatLocalTime()` that will display the time at that UTC offset.

```js
function getIANATimezone(utcOffsetSeconds) {
    const utcOffsetHours = Math.abs(utcOffsetSeconds / 3600);
    const sign = (utcOffsetSeconds < 0 ) ? '+': '-';
    return `Etc/GMT${sign}${utcOffsetHours}`;
}

function formatLocalTime(utcOffsetSeconds) {
    const timeZone = getIANATimezone(utcOffsetSeconds);
    return new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone });
}

const utcOffsets = [32400,-25200, 0, 3600];
console.log('UTC Offset(s)\tLocal time')
for(let utcOffset of utcOffsets) {
    console.log(utcOffset + '', '\t\t', formatLocalTime(utcOffset))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Hello, i've tried your code but im always receiving the global UTC time, and not the local time for a certain offset on some city around the world. i might have misunterstood the code or something, stil i really apreciate your answer thank you so much for your time

Comment: Thanks for testing the code! What OS / Browser are you testing this on? Is the function formatLocalTime(32400) showing you UTC time?  Thanks!

Comment: Hey, After reading your comment whether where i tested your code, it seems like that was the issue, i was using a Online Text Editor for quick testing, but after testing on my Node.js server it works perfectly fine, Again, thank you for taking your time!